# Solr8.0.0 date search issue

Tags: solr

I have an issue while searching on the Date field date_upload

My Schema file has the following entry for DATE Field

```
<field name="date_upload" type="pdate" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
```

My data-config.xml has the following entry -

```
<dataConfig>
<dataSource type="JdbcDataSource"
            driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
            batchSize="-1"
            autoReconnect="true"
            socketTimeout="0"
            connectTimeout="0"
            encoding="UTF-8"
            url="jdbc:mysql://xxx.xxx.xxx.xx:3306/news?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull"
            user="admin"
            password="admin"/>
<document>
<!--<entity name="news10" query="select * from news10"
            deltaQuery="select posting_id from item where last_modified > '${dataimporter.last_index_time}'"> 
</entity>-->
<entity name="news10" pk="posting_id"
  query="SELECT * FROM news10"
  deltaImportQuery="SELECT * FROM news10
    WHERE posting_id = '${dataimporter.delta.posting_id}'"
  deltaQuery="SELECT posting_id FROM news10
    WHERE last_modified > '${dataimporter.last_index_time}'">
</entity>
</document>
</dataConfig>
```

The following do not work -
fq=date_upload:NOW  *(does not work)*
http://localhost:8983/solr/Nlive/select?fq=date_c%3ANOW&q=*%3A*

fq=date_upload:NOW-1DAY  *(does not work)*
fq=date_upload:(NOW-30DAYS)  *(does not work)*

fq=date_upload:[2018-12-01T:00:00:00Z TO 2019-04-17T00:00:00Z]  *(does not work)*

```
"msg":"Invalid Date in Date Math String:'2018-12-01T:00:00:00Z'",
```

fq=date_upload:[2018-12-01 TO 2019-04-17] Gives the following error

```
{
  "responseHeader":{
    "status":400,
    "QTime":1,
    "params":{
      "q":"*:*",
      "fq":"date_upload:[2018-12-01 TO 2019-04-17]",
      "_":"1555386354522"}},
  "error":{
    "metadata":[
      "error-class","org.apache.solr.common.SolrException",
      "root-error-class","org.apache.solr.common.SolrException"],
    "msg":"Invalid Date String:'2018-12-01'",
    "code":400}}
```

However these do give results -
fq=date_upload:[* TO NOW]
http://localhost:8983/solr/Nlive/select??fq=date_c%3A%5B*%20TO%20NOW%5D&q=*%3A*

Comment: Added the following in the Schema file -  <br/>

_<fieldType name="date_range" class="solr.DateRangeField"/>_  <br/><br/>

And modified  <br/>
_<field name="date_upload" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true" />_  <br/>
to  <br/>
_<field name="date_upload" type="date_range" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true" />_  <br/>

Still the following not working  <br/>
NOW  <br/>
NOW-7DAYS  <br/>
NOW-30DAYS  <br/>

The following has started working  <br/>
_fq=date_upload:[2018-12-01 TO 2019-04-17]_

Answer (score 0):

The error is trying to tell you that `2018-12-01T:00:00:00Z` is an invalid timestamp - which it is. There's an additional `:` there that should be there:

```
2018-12-01T:00:00:00Z
           ^
```

Using the correct form, `2018-12-01T00:00:00Z` should work as you expect it to (and is what you've used as the end of the range).

For your other examples, `fq=date_upload:NOW-1DAY` says "Give me any documents where the datetimestamp is EXACTLY one day ago at this millisecond". That probably won't give you any documents. In those cases you want to use a range as well, such as `[NOW-1DAY TO *]`